# Run Python script from anywhere

Tags: shell-script, python

I'm defining a bash function in my `.bash_profile` so that I can run a certain Python script from any directory. My function is something like this:

```
func()
{
     python -i ~/Scripts/script.py
}
```

It works perfectly from my home directory, but it cant find the directory `./Scripts/script.py` if run from anywhere else.

The error message is:

> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'Projects/sym.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Shouldn't the `~` initially direct to the home directory anyways?

Comment: It is "something like this" or it looks exactly like that? Can you paste your actual code? And can you paste in the exact error message you receive?

Comment: Code is exactly like that semantically. The error message `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'Projects/sym.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message:

> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'Projects/sym.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

you can see that your `~/Scripts/script.py` tries to reference another file using a relative path `Projects/sym.py`.

Most likely you are calling the `func` function when your current directory is set to one that does not contain `Projects/sym.py`.

If your intention is to include a file from `~/Projects/sym.py` you need to use an absolute path in the Python code or change the current directory to `~` inside the `func` prior to calling `python`.